# What methods should be used to model the curved lip on this model?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

I'm about 6 weeks or so into learning blender, and I'm working on this model for a scene I'm doing. I've used what I've learned from the few tutorials I've done so far and got this far.

I'm stumped on how model the piece I've circled on my reference photo, I've done some boolean operations and I tried to make it by extending out that top edge and using a boolean with a cylinder like I did for other parts of this, but it just wouldn't come out right. I've also tried just manually extending and bending it but the nature of the curves on multiple axes makes that very difficult and I assume there's a simpler way that I'm just not aware of.

Any advice is appreciated!

[image: Pipettor]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ***Bevel*** tool:

- Create a 90° angle, bevel it:

[image]

[image]

- Select the bottom vertices, same thing, bevel them with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

- Create additional topology if necessary (use the knife tool, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally):

[image]

- Extrude with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

Comment: This does seem like the way to do it, however I'm having a bit of trouble with the topology. Could you follow up a bit on the logic behind how you should create the topology? My topology is a little messed up, I think, because I am attaching this to a cylindrical object.

Since the part I need to attach this to is extruded from a cylinder, the vertices get closer together as you get to the edges of the object. Is there a method to help with something like that?

Comment: maybe share your object, at least the cylinder you are talking about? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/